# Populating dropdown from database via Struts 2 action class (using jtable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, struts2, jquery-jtable

I am using jtable http://jtable.org/ in my project. jTable is a jQuery plugin that is used to create AJAX based CRUD tables without coding HTML or Javascript.

http://i62.tinypic.com/3461eo3.jpg

jtable code for above form is

HTML code:

```html
<div id="StudentTableContainer"></div>
```

JavaScript code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">  
  
   
  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
  
   
  
        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({  
  
            title: 'Student List',  
  
            paging: true,  
  
            pageSize: 10,  
  
            sorting: true,  
  
            defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',  
  
            actions: {  
  
                listAction: '/Demo/StudentList',  
  
                deleteAction: '/Demo/DeleteStudent',  
  
                updateAction: '/Demo/UpdateStudent',  
  
                createAction: '/Demo/CreateStudent'  
  
            },  
  
            fields: {  
  
                StudentId: {  
  
                    key: true,  
  
                    create: false,  
  
                    edit: false,  
  
                    list: false  
  
                },  
  
                Name: {  
  
                    title: 'Name',  
  
                    width: '30%'  
  
                },  
  
                EmailAddress: {  
  
                    title: 'Email address',  
  
                    list: false  
  
                },  
  
                Password: {  
  
                    title: 'User Password',  
  
                    type: 'password',  
  
                    list: false  
  
                },  
  
                Gender: {  
  
                    title: 'Gender',  
  
                    options: { 'M': 'Male', 'F': 'Female' },  
  
                    list: false  
  
                },  
  
                ContinentalId: {  
  
                    title: 'Continental',  
  
                    options: '/Demo/GetContinentalOptions',  
  
                    list: false  
  
                },  
  
                CountryId: {  
  
                    title: 'Country',  
  
                    dependsOn: 'ContinentalId', //Countries depends on continentals. Thus, jTable builds cascade dropdowns!  
  
                    options: function (data) {  
  
                        if (data.source == 'list') {  
  
                            //Return url of all countries for optimization.   
  
                            //This method is called for each row on the table and jTable caches options based on this url.  
  
                            return '/Demo/GetCountryOptions?continentalId=0';  
  
                        }  
  
   
  
                        //This code runs when user opens edit/create form or changes continental combobox on an edit/create form.  
  
                        //data.source == 'edit' || data.source == 'create'  
  
                        return '/Demo/GetCountryOptions?continentalId=' + data.dependedValues.ContinentalId;  
  
                    },  
  
                    list: false  
  
                },  
  
                CityId: {  
  
                    title: 'City',  
  
                    width: '30%',  
  
                    dependsOn: 'CountryId', //Cities depends on countries. Thus, jTable builds cascade dropdowns!  
  
                    options: function (data) {  
  
                        if (data.source == 'list') {  
  
                            //Return url of all cities for optimization.   
  
                            //This method is called for each row on the table and jTable caches options based on this url.  
  
                            return '/Demo/GetCityOptions?countryId=0';  
  
                        }  
  
   
  
                        //This code runs when user opens edit/create form or changes country combobox on an edit/create form.  
  
                        //data.source == 'edit' || data.source == 'create'  
  
                        return '/Demo/GetCityOptions?countryId=' + data.dependedValues.CountryId;  
  
                    }  
  
                },  
  
                BirthDate: {  
  
                    title: 'Birth date',  
  
                    type: 'date',  
  
                    displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  
  
                    list: false  
  
                },  
  
                Education: {  
  
                    title: 'Education',  
  
                    list: false,  
  
                    type: 'radiobutton',  
  
                    options: [  
  
                        { Value: '1', DisplayText: 'Primary school' },  
  
                        { Value: '2', DisplayText: 'High school' },  
  
                        { Value: '3', DisplayText: 'University' }  
  
                    ]  
  
                },  
  
                About: {  
  
                    title: 'About this person',  
  
                    type: 'textarea',  
  
                    list: false  
  
                },  
  
                IsActive: {  
  
                    title: 'Status',  
  
                    width: '15%',  
  
                    type: 'checkbox',  
  
                    values: { 'false': 'Passive', 'true': 'Active' },  
  
                    defaultValue: 'true'  
  
                },  
  
                RecordDate: {  
  
                    title: 'Record date',  
  
                    width: '25%',  
  
                    type: 'date',  
  
                    displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  
  
                    create: false,  
  
                    edit: false,  
  
                    sorting: false //This column is not sortable!  
  
                }  
  
            }  
  
        });  
  
   
  
        //Load student list from server  
  
        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');  
  
    });  
  
   
  
</script>
```

I want to have a Dropdown in my project which should take values from database through struts2 action class .
Like in the above demo code, list of continents can be accessed from database via struts2 action class (using URL pattern `/Demo/GetContinentalOptions`

As jtable only understands json so please guide me what should I write in Struts2 Action class and Struts.xml

Note: In your sample code you can even hardcode dropdown values

Answer (score 1):

You can populate your json field with the following action. You also need a [convention plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/convention-plugin.html) to use annotations. To use json result you need a [json plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html).

```
@Action(value="GetContinentalOptions", results=@Result(type="json", params = {"root", "map"}))
public class ContinentalOptionsAction extends ActionSupport {    
  Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();

  public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    return map;
  }

   @Override
   public String execute() throws Exception {
      map.put("1", "Asia");
      map.put("2", "America");
      map.put("3", "Europe");
      map.put("4", "Africa");
      return SUCCESS;
   }
}
```

In the `options` function

```
var options = []; 
$.ajax({ //get from server
    url: '<s:url action="GetContinentalOptions"/>',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        options = data;
    }
});
return options;
```

**EDIT:**

Without convention plugin you should write action configuration in `struts.xml`

```
<action name="GetContinentalOptions" class="com.action.ContinentalOptionsAction">
  <result type="json">
    <param name="root" value="map"/> 
  </result>
</action>
```

Comment: please guide me how it can be done without conventional plugin. And also provide the format of struts.xml

Comment: @Hirak see edit, added configuration in xml format, this is equivalent that I used previously via annotations.